# Installed Django with Pip but Python cant find it

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to install django, but I am not sure how to proceed.  I think I have installed django, but python python doesn't seem to be able to seethe package.

```
$ sudo pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

$ python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django; print(django.__path__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

How do I fix this?  When I try to run the server I get this error

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Comment: did you create a virtual environment (`virtualenv`) for your django installation?

Comment: no, I am just using the system python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pip` is using a different version of Python than your `python`. Check the output of these commands:

```
pip -V
python -V
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
```

There can be multiple versions of Python and Pip installed in your system.
For example in a Bash shell if you type `python` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> a few times it will show you the available Python binaries on your PATH, for example `python2.7`, `python3.4`, and similarly for `pip` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> too.

It depends on your system how to configure correctly so that both `python` and `pip` are using the same versions.

It would be best to use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You wouldn't have such problems, as in a virtualenv your Python version and Pip version would be well synchronized.

Judging by your command output, `pip` is using Python 2.7. One quick fix could be to try running Django like this:

```
python2.7 manage.py runserver
```

Or, to run the `pip` version corresponding to your default Python version.

This "quick fix" is a dirty fix. It would be best to use virtualenv.

Comment: `pip -V` pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
`python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'`
/usr/bin/python

Comment: Ok run this one too: `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`

Comment: Ah, ok, when I look at the pip source `vim /usr/local/bin/pip` I see `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`, but my python is /usr/bin/python

Comment: what's the output of `python -V` ?

Comment: I did an easy_install pip and it linked to the system python.  thanks!